# Laravel with OR and WHERE from raw query to Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can i convert this raw query to elequent ?

```
$data = DB::select("SELECT * FROM true_advances WHERE submitter_id = '". Auth::id() ."' OR (approval_id = '". Auth::id() ."' AND status != '0') ");
```

I try this code but get 0 row :

```
 $data = true_advance::where(function($query)
    {
        $query->where('status', '0')
        ->Where('approval_id', Auth::id());
    })->orWhere('submitter_id', Auth::id())->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this version:

```
$data = DB::table('true_advance')
    ->where('submitter_id', '=', Auth::id())
    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->where('approval_id', '=', Auth::id())
              ->where('status', '<>', '0');
        })
    ->get();
```

The version I gave above sticks with the order of logic used in your original query.  Your version might work, though, if not for the incorrect `status = 0` check (it should be `status <> 0` based on the raw query).

Comment: Wow, thnx, thats solve the problem ! though i more prefer true_advance::where, because this query have a relation in the model so i could get data from project table. But thnx a lot !